# CrystalRangeSeekbar not refelcting new value

Tags: android, rangeseekbar

I am using this [library](https://github.com/syedowaisali/crystal-range-seekbar) for range seekbar.

I wish to set a value when the view is loaded and i am using this code.

```
  rangeSeekbar_exp.setMinStartValue(seekerActivity.filter_sort.min_exp);
```

but it is not reflecting in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think by using the .apply() method at the end should do the trick.

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: Great. Thanks :-)

Comment: It's just helped. No more hoping.